# the software could not be found on any servers at this time : sccm issue

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I want to install sapience software and it's available at software center but when I click install it says unable to make changes to your software and in more information it says the software could not be found on any servers at this time  . Is there any solution for this ? How can I install this software into my machine . Please help . Any kind of link , clue will be helpfull

Comment: Did you distribute that software to the distribution point that is the correct one for this computer?

Comment: @Syberdoor thank you for reply . I really don't know this . I can't give you the proper answer . I just found some links that I need to check CAS.log . So I'm trying to do this . I don't have any clue how to solve this .

Comment: Well are you the administrator of this sccm server or do you just want to install the software that is advertised to your computer? In general when you create a package for any software you can chose to distribute the files for the installer to a server (unless they are located at a path that is accessible for all computers). In your case it looks as if this distribution was not done (or not done properly)

Comment: @Syberdoor I am not the administrator of this sccm . I just want to install this software into my laptop. Do you know how to solve this issue cause I really need this software to install and I can't download this software from net

Comment: @Syberdoor I found CAS.log and it says The number of discovered DPs(including Branch DP and Multicast) is 0 what is this means???

Comment: the DP is the server where the installer should be located. If you are not the admin of this sccm you should probably just contact them. There seems to be something misconfigured (either they forgot to dedicate a dp for your machine or they forgot to publish the package there (unfortunately it oculd also mean that you should not even see the software and that this is the real misconfiguration but you do not have the means to fix this problem without access to the sccm console). Unfortunately there is nothing you can do from your end but contact the correct admins

Comment: @Syberdoor I got your point . Thanks for explaining it to me :)